# Create another table when user profile table gets created with same ID

Tags: python, django, sqlite, data-structures, django-rest-framework

In my app i want to when a user profile is created, another table associated with the user profile id, gets created at the same time.

I'm new to Django. I've tried to create the table after `user.save()` in my models.py and serializers.py, by finding the current user_id
and then call `create(owner=user_id)` on the model object i want to create with user profile but it gives me `list index out of range`.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password' : {'write_only' : True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        '''Creates and returns new user.'''

        user = UserProfile(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        """here im trying to create the other tabel"""
        user_id = UserProfile.objects.filter(email='email').values('id')[0]['id']
        UserSessions.objects.create(owner_id=user_id)

        return user
```

In my model.py :

```
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Helps Django work with our custom user model."""

    def create_user(self, email, name, password):
        """Create a new user profile object."""

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address son!')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, models.Model):
    """Represent a user profile"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

In views.py :

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles CRU."""
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.Update_own_profile,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'id')
```

I'm trying to add this model with userprofile :

```
class UserSessions(models.Model):
    sessions_list_id = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    owner_id         = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=0)
    total_Sessions   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: What's more - why do you need `UserSession` to have the same `id` as your `UserProfile`?

Comment: i needed a way to get the `UserSession` associated with a specific `UserProfile`, so i could find both when client sends his id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - welcome to the Django community!
Let's drive right in.
In regards to your terminology, you're not trying to add a table, but to insert a row into the database.

More specifically, you are trying to create and associate a `UserProfile` instance with an instance of `UserSessions`. To achieve this, you can simply implement the following logic in the `create` method in your serializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = UserProfile
         fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password', )
         extra_kwargs = {'password' : {'write_only' : True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        '''Creates and returns new user.'''

        user = UserProfile(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        UserSessions.objects.create(sessions_list_id=user)

        return user
```

Note that I'm not passing the `UserProfile` id to `owner_id`, but the entire instance to `sessions_list_id`. The `ForeignKey` field enables you to define inter table relationships and is the field where you want to associate two instances. Hence, this also alleviates the necessity of having a separate `owner_id` field, which you seem to use to save owner specific information. Also, you should consider a more semantic naming like `user_profile` for the key name and maybe add a `related_name` to it like so:

```
user_profile = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='sessions')
```

This allows you to get a `queryset` of all sessions associated with a `UserProfile` `u_prof` like so:

```
sessions = u_prof.sessions.all()
```

In case you want to implement your own session handling, Django comes with that right of the box (just fyi).

That said, there are a couple of things, that bother me. As you are new to Django, I assume that creating your new `User` model was the intuitive choice to go. Imho, as a beginner, you should not bother about implementing a custom User model, but rather go with the go to approach of associating a Profile model with your user, which takes care of the additional information you need to store:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    # any info you need to store

# in any view/ serializer, you can then access the profile like so
profile = user.profile
```

This also enforces separation of concerns in the sense that it lets the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` take care of authentication, while the application's models get implemented in the `Profile` model.
A shortcoming of this is that your `User` JSON representation gets nested and introduces the need of nested updates, when you want the give the client the ability to update profile information on the front end. However, as this is a commonly used technique, the docs of django rest framework even have a dedicated section for this: [see here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

Comment: Thank you so much, warm welcome and great answer!  i've got it. about the custom model, as you're suggesting i'm definitely going to go with the default profile model. thanks for pointing that out.